# System.AccessViolationException using EmguCV

Tags: c#, opencv, exception, emgucv, access-violation

I want to find outliers in sets of keypoints from matches of consecutive frames. I use EmguCV - a wrapper of `OpenCV` and `Visual Studio Express 2012` on Windows 7 64bits.

I tried to use this function

```
Features2DToolbox.GetHomographyMatrixFromMatchedFeatures,
```

and I get an exception which is shown below: Sometimes this happens after few seconds, Sometimes almost immediately.

Another wierd thing is that even if the function is in `try-catch block` I can't catch an exception

Here is part of my code:

```
        m_foundedPreviousSkyKeyPoints = new VectorOfKeyPoint(m_foundedCurrentSkyKeyPoints.ToArray());
        m_matcherSky.Add(m_descriptorsSky);          
        m_detector.DetectAndCompute(m_currentFrame, m_maskForSky, m_foundedCurrentSkyKeyPoints, m_descriptorsSky, false);
        m_maskMatchesSky = new Mat(m_descriptorsSky.Rows, 1, DepthType.Cv8U,1);
        m_matcherSky.KnnMatch(m_descriptorsSky, m_matchesSky, neighboursNumber, null);
        try
        {   
                Features2DToolbox.GetHomographyMatrixFromMatchedFeatures(
                m_foundedPreviousSkyKeyPoints,
                m_foundedCurrentSkyKeyPoints,
                m_matchesSky,
                m_maskMatchesSky,
                10.0d);
        }
        catch (System.AccessViolationException e) //does not catch exception 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
```

And the exception I get:

> An unhandled exception of type `'System.AccessViolationException'` occurred in `Emgu.CV.dll`
>
> Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

I have no idea what is the reason, any help is appreciated

Comment: You cannot catch this exception, because `AccessViolationException` is a Win32 SEH exception. By default, .NET 3.5+ doesn't allow you to catch those exceptions (you can change this behavior in app.config though, if you want, but be careful).